# Qt WebEngineView render empty image

Tags: qt, qwebengineview

I am using qt 5.6.2. I would like to take a screenshot on a web page. Here is the code I am using:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWebEngineWidgets/QWebEngineView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int left, top, width, height;
    left = 0;
    top = 0;
    width = 600;
    height = 800;

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWebEngineView* w = new QWebEngineView();
    QImage image(height, width, QImage::Format_RGB32);
    QRegion rg(left, top, width, height);
    QPainter painter(&image);
    w->page()->load(QUrl("https://www.yahoo.com"));
    w->show();
    w->page()->view()->render(&painter, QPoint(), rg);
    painter.end();
    image.save("test.png", "PNG", 80);

    return a.exec();
}
```

I run the program, a window shows up, I can see the content of `yahoo`. I then save the result to `test.png` but that is a white picture. Is it I cannot save the result to `image` or I cannot save the result from `image` to file `test.png`and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the page to finish loading.

```
QWebEngineView* w = new QWebEngineView();
w->page()->load(QUrl("https://www.yahoo.com"));
w->show();


QObject::connect(w, &QWebEngineView::loadFinished,
                 [w](bool bOk)
{
    int left, top, width, height;
    left = 0;
    top = 0;
    width = 600;
    height = 800;

    QImage image(height, width, QImage::Format_RGB32);
    QRegion rg(left, top, width, height);
    QPainter painter(&image);
    w->page()->view()->render(&painter, QPoint(), rg);
    painter.end();
    image.save("test.png", "PNG", 80);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was struggling.